# How to resolve "Error: Cannot find module 'fsevents'" when using Vite on Windows?

Tags: javascript, windows, vite, fsevents

I am trying to use Vite for a web development project on my Windows machine. However, I keep getting the error message:
Error: Cannot find module 'fsevents'
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "fsevents" from "node_modules.vite\deps\chunk-7EWWWNQA.js?v=554e11ec". Does the file exist?

```
 async function loadFsEvents() { 
     try {
       ({ default: fsEvents } = await import("fsevents"));
   } catch (error2) {
     fsEventsImportError = error2; 
   }
```

I have tried uninstalling the fsevents package and deleting node modules several times, but the error persists. I also tried running the command npm audit fix --force, but it did not help either.

How can I resolve this error and use Vite on my Windows machine?

Comment: `fsevents` is Mac only and your Windows machine should be skipping that dependency. Is there anything peculiar about your setup?

Answer (score 23):

Check if you have any weird imports in any of your components. Sometimes autocomplete imports things by accident. I just resolved the same problem by deleting

```
import { SplitVendorChunkCahe } from 'vite'
```

line from a file.

Comment: Thanks for the help, turns out i had to remove a similar line

Comment: Same for me, I was accidentally importing viteConfig from vite.config.js

Comment: Thank you @ignas. Buried way into my code was a pesky import and its usage.  I thought autocorrect issues was only a 'smart' phone "First World Problem". VSCode trying to think for me.  :-D

Comment: Thanks for this, Accidentally added one line from vite. Now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with astro.js

`failed to resolve import fsevents from node_modules\.vite\deps\chunk-vdeja7du.js?v=f80aa972. does the file exist?`

Basically i was doing one wrong import in one file.
Just check your import items, that you are importing them from the right library or not.

I was importing React from @astro/react, and that was not available that's why i got this error.